passportjs + googleoauth20 + express-session (valkey store optional) req.user undefined
I'm so tired i spent the whole day trying to fix it but no matter what i do it's not working all i get is undefined PLEASE PLEASE HELP!!!!
The Problem is that I'm getting req.user property as undefined after successfully authenticating the user.
I Uploaded All The code On GitHub
https://github.com/Parag-47/OTX-Backend
But Here The Main Files If You Wanna Take A Looki.
Here Is MY App.js
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import mongoSanitize from "express-mongo-sanitize";
import cors from "cors";
import hpp from "hpp";
import session from "express-session";
import redisStore from "./db/valkey.js";
import auth from "./middlewares/auth.js";
import myPassport from "./services/passport.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.routes.js";

const cookieOptions = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: false, //Change To True In Production Very Important******
  //sameSite: "none" //uncomment in prod so it only accept request from one site  
};

const sessionOptions = {
  name: "sessionId",
  //store: redisStore,
  resave: false, // required: force lightweight session keep alive (touch)
  saveUninitialized: true, // false recommended: only save session when data exists
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: cookieOptions,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
}

const app = express();

//app.set("trust proxy", 1); //for proxy related issues

app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  })
);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "16kb" }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session(sessionOptions));
app.use(myPassport.initialize());
app.use(myPassport.session());
app.use(myPassport.authenticate("session"));
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "16kb" }));

app.use(hpp());
app.use(mongoSanitize());

app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).json({ Message: "Hi!" }));
app.get("/home", auth ,(req, res) =>
  res.status(200).json({ Message: "Successfully Logged In!" })
);

export default app;

Here Is My Passport.js

import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import { User } from "../models/user.model.js";

const myPassport = new passport.Passport();

myPassport.serializeUser((user, cb)=>{
  const data = {
    id: user.id,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    name: user.name,
    emails: user.emails,
    photos: user.photos,
  };
  console.log("Got Serialized: ", user);
  cb(null, data);
});

myPassport.deserializeUser((user, cb)=>{
  console.log("Got Called: ", user);
  cb(null, user);
});

const AUTH_OPTIONS = {
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/google/callback",
  scope: ["profile"],
  session: true,
};

async function verifyCallback(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // console.log(accessToken);
  // console.log(refreshToken);
  //console.log("Google Profile: ", profile);
  
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({email: profile.emails[0].value});
    if(existingUser) return done(null, profile);
    const user = await User.create({name: profile.displayName, email: profile.emails[0].value});
    return done(null, profile);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
    return done("Something Went Wrong!", profile);
  }
  
  //Create User Record And If Any Error Pass The Error To Passport Through Callback.
  //Replace Null With The Error.
}

myPassport.use(new GoogleStrategy(AUTH_OPTIONS, verifyCallback));

export default myPassport;

Here Is MY Routes.js
import { Router } from "express";
import auth from "../middlewares/auth.js";
import validateDto from "../middlewares/validateDto.middleware.js";
import validate from "../validation/jsonSchema.js";
import myPassport from "../services/passport.js";
import { register, login } from "../controllers/user.controller.js";

const userRouter = Router();

const googleAuth = myPassport.authenticate("google", {
  scope: ["email", "profile"],
});
const googleAuthCallback = myPassport.authenticate("google", {
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  successRedirect: "/home",
});

userRouter.get("/auth/google", googleAuth);
userRouter.get("/auth/google/callback", googleAuthCallback);
userRouter.post("/register", register);
userRouter.get("/login", login);

export default userRouter;

And Here The Controller.js
import { User } from "../models/user.model.js";
import asyncHandler from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
import ApiError from "../utils/ApiError.js";
import ApiResponse from "../utils/ApiResponse.js";

const register = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) console.log("rec");
    console.log("Test: ", req.session, req.session.user, req.user, req.log, req.local);
  res.send("OK");
});

const login = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "Login Failed Try Again!");
  }
  res.status(302).redirect("/home");
});

export { register, login };

I Tried Looking The docs and tutorials but nothing helped

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Nobody Helped Me So I Just Implemented Google OAuth 2 From Scratch Without Using Any Libraries It was way Easier And Fun.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
